# Strange behaviour when using std::async with std::launch::async

Tags: c++, stdasync, std-future

I am trying to wrap my head around `std::async` and `std::futures` introduced in C++11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

int hog_cpu()
{
    cout << "hog_cpu" << endl;
    volatile unsigned long long i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 1000000000ULL ; i++);
    return 50;
}

int hog_cpu_ex()
{
    cout << "hog_cpu_ex" << endl;
    volatile unsigned long long i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 1000000000ULL ; i++);
    return 500;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "start threads asynchronously" << endl;

    std::future<int> f1 = std::async(std::launch::async, hog_cpu);

    std::future<int> f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, hog_cpu_ex);

    cout << "Get the Results" << endl;

    int r1 = f1.get();

    int r2 = f2.get();

    cout << "result 1: " << r1 << endl;
    cout << "result 2: " << r2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program that I get is shown below.

```
start threads asynchronously
Get the Results
hog_cpu_ex
hog_cpu
result 1: 50
result 2: 500

Process finished with exit code 0
```

My question is since I use `std::launch::async` the execution should start immideately using another thread.  Where as the output tells me that it prints the line `Get the results` and then only the execution starts. (As evident from the logs above). Also `hog_cpu_ex` starts before `hog_cpu`. Can someone explain why this might be happening.

Comment: The scheduler decides when to run which thread, so there is no point in even trying to explain why X runs before Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
std::future<int> f1 = std::async(std::launch::async, hog_cpu);

std::future<int> f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, hog_cpu_ex);
```

You spin up two more threads of execution.  Then the main thread keeps going after it calls each line and won't stop until it hits

```
int r1 = f1.get();
```

if `f1` hasn't finished yet.  Since the main thread keeps going and spinning up a thread takes some time it is pretty reasonable to see `Get the Results` print before the threads even start.

As for why do you see

```
hog_cpu_ex
hog_cpu
```

instead of the opposite is due to your operating system.  It has control over which threads run and when so it is quite possible that it puts `f1` to sleep, has space for `f2` so it starts it running, and then starts `f1` sometime after that.